# How to be sure bibliography is complete?

Tags: biblatex, xetex

I am writing a thesis with A LOT of references.

The doctoral school wants me to divide the bibliography per type (article, book etc).

I am using `XeLaTeX` with `biblatex`.

When I use `\printbibliography` there's no problem.

But when I divide into parts, I don't get any warning that I cite a reference which is not in the bibliography.

Here is an MWE that shows the issue. The book is properly referenced in the bibliography, but not the article. That's quite a normal behavior given what I asked, but I'd wish to get a warning.

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibli.bib}
@book{geertz1993LocalKnowledgeFurther,
  title = {Local Knowledge: Further Essays in Interpretive Anthropology},
  date = {1993},
  author = {Geertz, Clifford}
}

@article{gomez-baggethun2013TraditionalEcologicalKnowledge,
  title = {Traditional {{Ecological Knowledge}} and {{Global Environmental Change}}: {{Research}} Findings and Policy Implications},
  date = {2013},
  author = {Gómez-Baggethun, Erik and Corbera, Esteve and Reyes-García, Victoria}
}
\end{filecontents}    


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        style=authoryear-icomp, 
        autocite=inline, 
        maxbibnames=99, 
        date=year]
        {biblatex}
\bibliography{bibli.bib}

\begin{document}

    This is a great book \autocite{geertz1993LocalKnowledgeFurther}. This is a great article \autocite{gomez-baggethun2013TraditionalEcologicalKnowledge}.

    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, type=book, title={Books}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I'd have a bibliography with a set of `nottype=...` to pick up anything missing from anything that selects types. As you create each specific bibliography, that should shrink. When it shrinks to nothing, you're done!

Comment: ok thanks, I tried this. It kind of works but not entirely.
How should I show what I did?
I added a @thesis. and tried this `    \defbibfilter{citedTypes}{
   type=book or
   type=article
    }
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, type=book, title={Books}]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, type=article, title={Articles}]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, nottype=citedTypes, title={Others1}]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, nottype=book, title={Others2}]
    `
I others1, everything is listed; in others2 everthing but books

Comment: You can edit your question to update it. I think you need `nottype=book,nottype=article,nottype=...`. However, you might get complications with types which are being mapped to other types - I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was busy submitting my thesis :-). Your solution works, I'll answer my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Paul Stanley and cfr, I was able to answer my own question. Adding several `nottype` is working!

```
\begin{filecontents}{bibli.bib}
@book{geertz1993LocalKnowledgeFurther,
  title = {Local Knowledge: Further Essays in Interpretive Anthropology},
  date = {1993},
  author = {Geertz, Clifford}
}

@article{gomez-baggethun2013TraditionalEcologicalKnowledge,
  title = {Traditional {{Ecological Knowledge}} and {{Global Environmental Change}}: {{Research}} Findings and Policy Implications},
  date = {2013},
  author = {Gómez-Baggethun, Erik and Corbera, Esteve and Reyes-García, Victoria}
}


@thesis{leroy1970SystemeFoncierDeveloppement,
  title = {Système foncier et développement rural. Essai d'anthropologie juridique sur la répartition des terres chez les Wolof ruraux de la zone arachidière-nord (République du Sénégal)},
  date = {1970},
  author = {Le Roy, Étienne}
}
\end{filecontents}    


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
        backend=biber,
        style=authoryear-icomp, 
        autocite=inline, 
        date=year]
        {biblatex}
\bibliography{bibli.bib}

\begin{document}

    This is a great book \autocite{geertz1993LocalKnowledgeFurther}. This is a great article \autocite{gomez-baggethun2013TraditionalEcologicalKnowledge}. And finally, a thesis that can't be missed \autocite{leroy1970SystemeFoncierDeveloppement}.


    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, type=book, title={Books}]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, type=article, title={Articles}]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, nottype=book, nottype=article, title={Others}]

\end{document}
```